# Keycloak : Liquibase error on startup linked with oracle-database on startup

Tags: oracle, docker, docker-compose, keycloak, liquibase

I'm looking to integrate Keycloak to an existing stack for my company.
The stack consists of an Oracle-Database (v19.3), the keycloak I'm trying to implement (latest so 23.0) and some other elements that should not interact with the problem. The stack do not contain Spring.database

I'm using a docker-compose file to launch the services :

```
version : '3.8'

volumes:
  oracle-orcl-data:
    external:
      name: ${oracle_db_volume_name}
services :
  oracle-database:
    image: container-registry.oracle.com/database/enterprise:19.3.0.0
    volumes:
      - oracle-orcl-data:/ORCL
      - ${oracle_db_home}/dump:/opt/oracle-dump
    ports:
      - "1521:1521"
      - "5500:5500"
    healthcheck:
      test: [ "CMD","/opt/oracle/checkDBStatus.sh"]
      interval: 2s
    environment:
      - ORACLE_PDB=ORCLPDB1
keycloak:
    depends_on:
      oracle-database:
        condition: service_healthy
    links:
      - oracle-database
    image: quay.io/keycloak/keycloak:latest
    command: start-dev
    hostname: keycloak
    ports:
      - "8081:8080"
    environment:
      KC_DB: oracle
      KC_DB_URL_HOST: oracle-database
      KC_DB_URL_DATABASE: orclpdb1
      KC_DB_PASSWORD: [REDACTED]
      KC_DB_USERNAME: keycloak
      KC_DB_SCHEMA: keycloak
      KEYCLOAK_ADMIN: [REDACTED]
      KEYCLOAK_ADMIN_PASSWORD: [REDACTED]
```

Note : this is not the complete file, some elements are proprietary and have been redacted.
The healthcheck on oracle-database is OK, and keycloak launches, and tried to apply liquibase changes to the database.

Then, the error occurs :

```
2024-02-16 09:34:42,137 INFO  [org.keycloak.quarkus.runtime.storage.legacy.liquibase.QuarkusJpaUpdaterProvider] (main) Initializing database schema. Using changelog META-INF/jpa-changelog-master.xml
2024-02-16 09:34:49,040 ERROR [liquibase.changelog.ChangeSet] (main) ChangeSet META-INF/jpa-changelog-2.5.0.xml::2.5.0-unicode-oracle::hmlnarik@redhat.com encountered an exception.
2024-02-16 09:34:49,075 ERROR [org.keycloak.quarkus.runtime.cli.ExecutionExceptionHandler] (main) ERROR: Failed to start server in (development) mode
2024-02-16 09:34:49,075 ERROR [org.keycloak.quarkus.runtime.cli.ExecutionExceptionHandler] (main) ERROR: Failed to update database
2024-02-16 09:34:49,075 ERROR [org.keycloak.quarkus.runtime.cli.ExecutionExceptionHandler] (main) ERROR: liquibase.exception.LiquibaseException: liquibase.exception.MigrationFailedException: Migration failed for changeset META-INF/jpa-changelog-2.5.0.xml::2.5.0-unicode-oracle::hmlnarik@redhat.com:
     Reason: liquibase.exception.DatabaseException: ORA-00942: table or view does not exist

https://docs.oracle.com/error-help/db/ora-00942/ [Failed SQL: (942) UPDATE COMPONENT_CONFIG SET VALUE_NEW = VALUE, VALUE = NULL]
2024-02-16 09:34:49,075 ERROR [org.keycloak.quarkus.runtime.cli.ExecutionExceptionHandler] (main) ERROR: liquibase.exception.MigrationFailedException: Migration failed for changeset META-INF/jpa-changelog-2.5.0.xml::2.5.0-unicode-oracle::hmlnarik@redhat.com:
     Reason: liquibase.exception.DatabaseException: ORA-00942: table or view does not exist

https://docs.oracle.com/error-help/db/ora-00942/ [Failed SQL: (942) UPDATE COMPONENT_CONFIG SET VALUE_NEW = VALUE, VALUE = NULL]
2024-02-16 09:34:49,075 ERROR [org.keycloak.quarkus.runtime.cli.ExecutionExceptionHandler] (main) ERROR: Migration failed for changeset META-INF/jpa-changelog-2.5.0.xml::2.5.0-unicode-oracle::hmlnarik@redhat.com:
     Reason: liquibase.exception.DatabaseException: ORA-00942: table or view does not exist

https://docs.oracle.com/error-help/db/ora-00942/ [Failed SQL: (942) UPDATE COMPONENT_CONFIG SET VALUE_NEW = VALUE, VALUE = NULL]
2024-02-16 09:34:49,075 ERROR [org.keycloak.quarkus.runtime.cli.ExecutionExceptionHandler] (main) ERROR: ORA-00942: table or view does not exist

https://docs.oracle.com/error-help/db/ora-00942/ [Failed SQL: (942) UPDATE COMPONENT_CONFIG SET VALUE_NEW = VALUE, VALUE = NULL]
2024-02-16 09:34:49,076 ERROR [org.keycloak.quarkus.runtime.cli.ExecutionExceptionHandler] (main) ERROR: ORA-00942: table or view does not exist

https://docs.oracle.com/error-help/db/ora-00942/
2024-02-16 09:34:49,076 ERROR [org.keycloak.quarkus.runtime.cli.ExecutionExceptionHandler] (main) ERROR: ORA-00942: table or view does not exist
```

There is no connection problem, as tables are created under keycloak user, in keycloak schema.
On subsequent restarts of the service, it indicates that the tables already exists (obviously).

I then have to manually delete created tables to get the first error.
I have not been able to find a solution, being new to keycloak and oracle is probably preventing me to easily find the solution.

I tried to change oracle-database version (if this was a compatibility issue), and I also tried to run in oracle-database the SQL request manually.
The request `UPDATE COMPONENT_CONFIG SET VALUE_NEW = VALUE, VALUE = NULL` returns the same error as Liquibase, so it is definitely a problem in that.
But if i run `UPDATE KEYCLOAK.COMPONENT_CONFIG SET VALUE_NEW = VALUE, VALUE = NULL` then it passes. So I guess the problem is regarding from *where* the request is executed.
I'm guessing there is an environment variable that I have forgotten in docker-compose, or something that would make this work, but I have not yet find it.

I also looked for a similar problem on SO and found nothing alike, idem on the Internet.

Thank you for any help you might give.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure why, but the following docker-compose.yml seems to have corrected the problem :

```
version : '3.8'

volumes:
  oracle-orcl-data:
    external:
      name: ${oracle_db_volume_name}
services :

  oracle-database:
    #image: store/oracle/database-enterprise:12.2.0.1-slim
    image: container-registry.oracle.com/database/enterprise:19.3.0.0
    volumes:
      - oracle-orcl-data:/ORCL
      - ${oracle_db_home}/dump:/opt/oracle-dump
    ports:
      - "1521:1521"
      - "5500:5500"
    healthcheck:
      test: [ "CMD","/opt/oracle/checkDBStatus.sh"]
      interval: 2s
    environment:
      ORACLE_PDB: ORCLPDB1
keycloak:
    depends_on:
      oracle-database:
        condition: service_healthy
    links:
      - oracle-database
    image: quay.io/keycloak/keycloak:latest
    command: start-dev
    hostname: keycloak
    ports:
      - "8081:8080"
    environment:
      KC_DB: oracle
      KC_DB_URL_HOST: oracle-database
      KC_DB_URL_DATABASE: orclpdb1
      KC_DB_PASSWORD: keycloak
      KC_DB_USERNAME: keycloak
      KC_DB_SCHEMA: keycloak
      KEYCLOAK_ADMIN: admin
      KEYCLOAK_ADMIN_PASSWORD: admin
```

I'm guessing the problem was linked to the ORACLE_PDB in environment, but I cannot be certain as the problem is no longer present.